How does a user whose account was created 15 days ago have posts from 2015 and 2017?
I see a user at a stackexchange site whose main account and meta accounts are both reported to have been created 15 days ago.
However, their meta account at that site posted a question in 2015 and posted an answer in 2017.
How is this possible?
(I can post a link, but it seems to be the norm to avoid making questions about an individual. Here, I do think a link would be innocuous — so just comment if you think a link would be helpful and appropriate in this case.)

That's very likely to be an account merge. And thanks for being careful!

It can also be due to migrated posts. If a user has made posts that were migrated to that site, and they (re)create their profile on that site, then those posts will be reattributed to their current profile.

related, maybe a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376302  Note that you can relatively easy find these accounts/posts with a SEDE query

This question is similar to: Why does this user have posts that appear to be older than their account?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. cc @rene I see why you didn't close as a dupe of that post (it being about SEDE and all), but this one looks to be a fit.
